# Rspec tests failing for phone number check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I've the below piece of code in `user_spec.rb` which was working great

```
#spec/models/user_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do

  it 'is invalid with an alternate phone number that is also that user\'s primary phone' do
    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, primary_phone: '123-456-7890', alternate_phone: '123-456-7890').save).to be_falsey
  end

end
```

until I changed the below code

```
#app/models/user.rb
def primary_phone=(num)
  write_attribute(:primary_phone, self.number_to_phone(num))
end
```

to

```
#app/models/user.rb
def primary_phone=(num)
  write_attribute(:primary_phone, self.number_to_phone(num, country_code: 1))
end
```

And now the tests are failing with the below error

```
Failures:

  1) User is invalid with an alternate phone number that is also that user's primary phone
     Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, primary_phone: '123-456-7890', alternate_phone: '123-456-7890').save).to be_falsey
       expected: falsey value
            got: true
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:62:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # /home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/database_cleaner-1.3.0/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:15:in `cleaning'
     # /home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/database_cleaner-1.3.0/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:92:in `cleaning'
     # /home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/database_cleaner-1.3.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
     # /home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/database_cleaner-1.3.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `call'
     # /home/pavan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/database_cleaner-1.3.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `cleaning'
     # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 19.04 seconds (files took 17.2 seconds to load)
118 examples, 1 failure, 70 pending
```

I thought the changed phone number format is causing the issue and changed

```
it 'is invalid with an alternate phone number that is also that user\'s primary phone' do
  expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, primary_phone: '123-456-7890', alternate_phone: '123-456-7890').save).to be_falsey
end
```

to

```
it 'is invalid with an alternate phone number that is also that user\'s primary phone' do
  expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, primary_phone: '+1-123-456-7890', alternate_phone: '+1-123-456-7890').save).to be_falsey
end
```

but the error exists. I've no idea what's going on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test now returns true because the user will have phone number `+1-123-456-7890` and your alternate number will be `123-456-7890`. This is because you prepend an extra `+1-` to your `primary_phone` but not to your `alternate_phone`.

You should either add this

```
def alternate_phone=(num)
  write_attribute(:alternate_phone, self.number_to_phone(num, country_code: 1))
end
```

Or change your test to

```
it 'is invalid with an alternate phone number that is also that user\'s primary phone' do
  expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user, primary_phone: '123-456-7890', alternate_phone: '+1-123-456-7890').save).to be_falsey
end
```

Comment: Did you read the question? I'm passing same values to both `primary_phone` and `alternate_phone`(i.e, +1-123-456-7890) and my tests are failing.

Comment: You changed `primary_phone=` to add `+1-` to the beginning but you don't do this for the `alternate_phone`. This means that they are not the same once you save the model. Your test asserts that you cannot save the model because the phones are the same, while in fact they are not.